# Way to do radio buttons in Qt 4.4.3 menus

Tags: qt, menu, radio-button

On Linux would like to have a set of menu items which are mutually exclusive and have the currently selected one be designated by a radio button instead of a checkbox.

Is there a way to do this in Qt v4.4.3 easily?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I believe you would want to use QtActionGroup to group those menu items which should be mutually exclusive. It also makes them look like a radio button when rendered. Smth like this:

```
QActionGroup* group = new QActionGroup( this );

ui->actionTest1->setCheckable(true);
ui->actionTest2->setCheckable(true);
ui->actionTest3->setCheckable(true);

ui->actionTest1->setActionGroup(group);
ui->actionTest2->setActionGroup(group);
ui->actionTest3->setActionGroup(group);
```

3 menu items above should be groped together; more details here : [QActionGroup Class Reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qactiongroup.html)

Comment: Does using 'windows' style prevent the rendering as radio button?

Comment: Note that the `setCheckable()` is not required if you turn on that flag in `designer`. You can also make sure that one of the items is checked by default.