# How do I setup a list of checkboxes in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, checkbox, menu, automation, qt-designer

In my window, I have one menu which is a set selections, one of which can be current. For example, in my Browser I have sub-menus where I can select the Zoom Factor.

For example, it could be offering three options like these:

```
  50%
√ 100%
  150%
```

Whenever the user selects one of the 50%, 100%, or 150%, the current selection needs to get unselected. I was hoping we could set that up in designer so it becomes automatic when I create the window. (i.e. the designer generated code would be smart enough to add those 3 items in a QActionGroup.)

[I've seen code that can be used to generate such a menu using QRadioButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918823/way-to-do-radio-buttons-in-qt-4-4-3-menus), but I don't see a way to replicate that behavior in designer. Is that not available in the tool?

Comment: It is possible to create a `QButtonGroup`, but not a `QActionGroup`.

Comment: "Unfortunately" menu items are `QAction` objects.

Comment: That task can not be done with Qt Designer since the assignment of widgets to a QAction is not possible, not the QButtonGroup. so you'll have to write some more code lines.

Comment: @AlexisWilke. I know that. That's why I said: ***but not*** a `QActionGroup`. I was simply pointing out that ***IF*** designer had a mechanism for creating a `QActionGroup`, it would very likely work in the same way as it does for `QButtonGroup`. That is, you would be able to select items in the action-editor, and then add them to a `QActionGroup` via the context menu (don't bother looking - it's not there). The only possible work-around would be to use widget promotion with a custom `QMenu` class. But that would only be worth doing if there were several menus that required action-groups.

Comment: PS: it seems that qt3 designer **did** have this functionality, but it has since been removed (and there are no plans to restore it). However, the [Qt Designer XML schema](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-ui-file-format.html) still defines an `ActionGroup` type, so it is possible to manually edit the ui file and add a `QActionGroup`. I assume this must also mean the uic tool can still generate the necessary code (I would guess for the purposes of backwards compatibility).

Comment: @ekhumoro Interest, although if not clearly documented I should probably not use that feature. Strange that they would have removed it. It seems to be a useful feature.